# Using a distinct statement over cursors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following:

[image: SQL Table]

At the moment I am using an inner cursor and outer cursor to go through every distinct(Column A) to get every Distinct(column B) values.

I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to do this in SQL but I'm still not 100% that the following statement will give me the result:

```
select distinct(columnA), columnB from Table order by columnA
```

Will that guarantee me a unique value of (ColumnA,ColumnB) ?

If so, does SQL server execute distinct on both ColumnA and columnB even though I only placed it on columnA? Do I not have to do groupings on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `CURSOR` for that. What you want are unique combinations of `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`. `DISTINCT` will do it for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA, ColumnB 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY ColumnA
```

---

[**DISTINCT**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php) will be executed on all columns in the `SELECT` query, you can't put it on a single column.

Answer (score 1):

you were practically there, just do a `distinct columnA, columnB from...`

like so:

```
select distinct columnA, columnB 
from Table 
order by columnA
```